# LitElement <slot> not wokring

Tags: lit-element

I'm creating my custom accordion element. In which I'll have 2 components 1 for ul and other for li.

Content in file accordion-ul.ts, in which I've a slot where I want my li.

```
import { html, customElement, property, LitElement } from 'lit-element';
import { Accordion } from 'carbon-components';

@customElement('accordion-panel')
export default class AccordionPanel extends LitElement {
  firstUpdated() {
    const accordionElement = document.getElementById('accordion');
    Accordion.create(accordionElement);
  }

  connectedCallback() {
    super.connectedCallback();
  }

  render() {
    return html`
      <ul data-accordion class="accordion" id="accordion">
        <slot></slot>
      </ul>
    `;
  }

  createRenderRoot() {
    return this;
  }
}
```

NOTE: I'm getting an error in the console in the firstUpdated() : Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'nodeName' of null.

The way I'm using it for testing:

```
<accordion-panel><li>test</li></accordion-panel>
```

IDK, it's not working and nothing is printing on the screen. On inspecting the element, I can see there's empty  in DOM.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your problem is that you're trying to use slots, which are a shadow DOM feature but you're not using shadow DOM (since you're overwriting the `createRenderRoot` method to prevent the creation of the `shadowRoot`)

So, if you want to use slots, just remove the `createRenderRoot` function from your class and use shadow DOM

Edit:
You should also update your `firstUpdated` method so that this part:

`const accordionElement = document.getElementById('accordion');`

Uses the element from your shadow DOM

`const accordionElement = this.shadowRoot.querySelector('.accordion');`

Then again, CarbonComponents styling will probably not work so you'll need to add those in some other way

Comment: If I try to remove the createRenderRoot, then I get an error: Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: DOM element should be given to initialize this widget.

Comment: you should also modify the firstupdated function so that it picks the element from shadow dom, I'll edit the answer with that extra info

Comment: Any idea on how to use external CSS with shadow DOM?

Comment: There are a couple of ways you could go about it, one is importing the file in your styles getter but that can lead to FOUC, other would be just plain copying the styles you need and adding them to your styles getter but this is a little hard to maintain, either way, trying to use solutions not intended originally for shadow dom in shadow dom will mostly have caveats like these

Comment: here's an example using mixins for theming -- (1) [component registration and mass-theming](https://github.com/chase-moskal/authoritarian-client/blob/master/source/startup/install-authoritarian.ts#L22) -- (2) [theme-components](https://github.com/chase-moskal/authoritarian-client/blob/master/source/framework/theme-components.ts) -- (3) [mixin-css](https://github.com/chase-moskal/authoritarian-client/blob/master/source/framework/mixin-css.ts) -- (4) [theme](https://github.com/chase-moskal/authoritarian-client/blob/master/source/system/theme.ts) -- (5) `source/components/user-panel.ts` L17

Comment: heh, i ran out of characters for the urls.. man, stack overflow sucks for this kind of thing.. also sorry to future people for when the links break, can't afford the full commit url's with the hash's `¯\_(ツ)_/¯` glhf